# Send control to method

Tags: c#, vb.net

I'm translating VB.NET code into C#.. there is a problem:

I have a method which gets `Control` objects and I need to send different controls to it

```
private void ApplyToAllPictureBoxes(ref Control oControl, ViewMode Mode)
{
    // ...
}

ApplyToAllPictureBoxes(ref Panel1, Mode);
ApplyToAllPictureBoxes(ref myFlowLayoutPanel, Mode);
```

But it throws

> "The best overloaded method match has some invalid arguments"

this is the VB.NET code:

```
Private Sub ApplyToAllPictureBoxes(ByRef oControl As Control, ByVal Mode As ViewMode)
    ' ... '
End Sub

ApplyToAllPictureBoxes(myFlowLayoutPanel, Mode)
ApplyToAllPictureBoxes(Panel1, Mode)
```

How can I do that?

Comment: fwiw, I bet the `ByRef` is a mistake in the original code, and `ByVal` would be good enough.

Answer (score 1):

Try it without `ref`, like this:

```
private void ApplyToAllPictureBoxes(Control oControl, ViewMode Mode)
{
    // ...
}
```

---

Usage:

```
ApplyToAllPictureBoxes(Panel1, Mode);
ApplyToAllPictureBoxes(myFlowLayoutPanel, Mode);
```

Comment: Glad it worked out, if you feel this answer helped you, then feel to accept the answer and up-vote the answer when you can. :-)